# Не работают минифицированные CSS и JS через защищенный протокол

Tags: javascript, css, apache, ssl

Здравствуйте. Использую [вот этот](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) minify на сайте. Все отлично работает. Но если я использую защищенный протокол (https) то все мои css и js стили и скрипты не обрабатываются (то есть стили не отображаются, скрипты не работают). При чем если я открою ссылку https://site.ru/min?g=css во вкладке браузера он отображает минифицированный код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

P.S. Пробовал подключать относительно (то есть /min?g=css) и указывая полный путь (https://site.ru/min?g=css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в ваш .htaccess строку:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы лучший)

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не точно изменили название темы. Если я стили и JS файлы подключаю напрямуюю, а не через минифай - все работает

Comment: @ИванЧуркин исправил. Выберете ответ лучшим?

Comment: Этот ответ был бы еще полезнее, если бы было написано почему вообще такая ошибка произошла и почему эта строка ее исправляет.